# Unable to apply otsu thresholding on gpu, opencv throws this: errorthreshold.cu:105: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type <= 4 in function 'threshold'

Tags: python, opencv, cuda, image-thresholding

I'm trying to do all my image processing in the GPU and not cpu processing:

```
# coding=utf8
import cv2

# Leer la imagen en la GPU
image = cv2.cuda_GpuMat()
image.upload(cv2.imread("sutil.jpeg"))
original = image


# Convertir la imagen de BGR a HSV en la GPU
image = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Convertir la imagen a escala de grises en la GPU
image = cv2.cuda.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# Binarizar la imagen en escala de grises con el método de Otsu en la GPU
ret, otsu = cv2.cuda.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Aplicar una máscara binaria a la imagen original del limón en la GPU
result = cv2.cuda.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=otsu)

# Mostrar la imagen resultante segmentada
cv2.imshow('Imágen Resultante Segmentada',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image]

However after apply the HSV conversion, the next step is apply otsu thresholding, and it is throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gpu.py", line 18, in <module>
    ret, otsu = cv2.cuda.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) /home/orin/opencv_contrib/modules/cudaarithm/src/cuda/threshold.cu:105: error: (-215:Assertion failed) type <= 4 in function 'threshold'
```

what does mean it "type <= 4 in function 'threshold'" I don't know why this happens, my code on cpu works perfectly:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("sutil.jpeg")
original = image

image = cv2.blur(image,(31,31),0)

# Convert BGR a HSV para saturar la imágen.

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#convertir a escala de grises (CV_RGB2GRAY)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Binarizar la imagen en escala de grises con el método de Otsu.
ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(image,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

#Aplicar mascara binaria a la imagen original del limón.
result = cv2.bitwise_and(original, original, mask=otsu)

cv2.imshow('Imagen Resultante Segmentada', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

also a detail in my gpu code version is that I removed "cv2.blur(image,(31,31),0)" because I can't do it, if you any idea guys to fix this two problems I will appreciate it.

thanks so much.

Comment: and your color conversions make no sense. the image starts out as BGR. your first conversion interprets that as BGR (ok...) and converts to HSV. your second conversion ***interprets*** the HSV as BGR (wrong!) and applies a conversion to "gray" that only makes sense if the input were BGR. you will get garbage. why do you not convert BGR2GRAY?

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/yangcha/38f2fa630e223a8546f9b48ebbb3e61a

Comment: @fmw42 no, wrong type of type. see my answer. additionally, even if that were an element type, <= 4 would cover the type resulting from imread and cvtcolor to gray

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz. Thanks. I understand.  Your answer makes more sense than the types I pointed to. But the error message seems a bit confusing to me. Nevertheless, it shows that one should always read the documentation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for your feedback, would you test your code and paste in your reply, I will appreciate it. I want to see it,

Comment: @fmw42 I didn't actually read the docs first, I just went straight for the .cu file. when the code told me, I checked the docs to make sure they said this too, and they do.

Comment: @FreddicMatters those color conversions did *not* contribute to causing the exception. they are a separate matter. -- I believe I have provided an explanation for that exception. -- you are free to implement Otsu thresholding, using OpenCV's CUDA-based functions as building blocks. you'll need a histogram.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz. Pardon my ignorance, but what is a .cu file and where can one find it/them?

Comment: the exception states the source file throwing the exception. usually that's something.cpp. here it's something.cu, so CUDA code. you can find the entire OpenCV source on their github. CUDA code is in the opencv_contrib repo.

Comment: It should be `ret, otsu = cv2.threshold(image,0,1,cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU` instead of `cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU`

Comment: @toyotaSupra `THRESH_OTSU` is the only value in the enum that has bit 3 set, so both produce the same result.

Comment: the `+` and `|` result in the same value because their one-bits are disjoint. THRESH_BINARY is `0`, so it doesn't even matter.

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d34/group__cudaarithm__elem.html#ga40f1c94ae9a9456df3cad48e3cb008e1) states:

> The `THRESH_OTSU` and `THRESH_TRIANGLE` threshold types are ***not supported.***

Comment: Please rectify my code, thanks in advance.

Comment: @FreddicMatters there's nothing to "rectify" - THRESH_OTSU is not supported on GPU thresholding

Comment: Ok I understand. thanks sir.